# Node Docker Build and Production Container Best Practices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, docker, alpine-linux

I have a Node project that uses MongoDB.  To for automated testing, we use [Mongo Memory Server](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server)

For Mongo Memory Server, Alpine is not supported my Mongo, so it can't run on Alpine images

From the docs:

> There isn't currently an official MongoDB release for alpine linux. This means that we can't pull binaries for Alpine (or any other platform that isn't officially supported by MongoDB), but you can use a Docker image that already has mongod built in and then set the MONGOMS_SYSTEM_BINARY variable to point at that binary. This should allow you to use mongodb-memory-server on any system on which you can install mongod.

I can run all of my tests in a Docker container using a Node base image, but for production I want to use an Alpine image to save on memory.

so my Dockerfile looks something like this.

```
FROM node:x.x.x as test

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

npm install
npm run build # we use Typescript, this runs the transpilation
npm test # runs our automated tests

FROM node:x.x.x-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=test /app/src /app/src
COPY --from=test /app/package.json /app/package.json
COPY --from=test /app/package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
COPY --from=test /app/config /app/config
COPY --from=test /app/scripts /app/scripts

RUN npm install --production

RUN npm run build
```

Doing smoke testing, the resulting Alpine image seems to work okay.  I assume it is safe because I install the modules in the alpine image itself.

I am wondering, is this the best practice?  Is there a better way to do something like this?  That is, for Node specifically, have a larger test container and a small production container safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points

1. If you are building twice, what is the point of the multistage build. I don't do much `node` stuff. But the reason you would want a multistage build is that you build you application with `npm build` that take those artifacts and copy them to the image and serve/run that in some way. In `go` world it would be something like building in a builder stage then just running the binary.
2. You always want to have the most changing things on the top of the union file system. What it means is that instead of copying the entire application code and running `npm install`, you should copy just `package.json` and run `npm install` on it. That way docker can cache the result of npm install and save on downloading the node files if nothing has changed on top. You application code changes way more than the `package.json`
3. On the second stage same idea. If you have to - copy `package.json` first and run `npm install` then copy the rest of the stuff.
4. You can have more stages if you want. The name of the game is to get the leanest and cleanest final stage image. Thats the one that goes on registry. Everything else can be and should be removed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So the reason I do another install in the final container, is that I am not sure if the install in the test container is compatible with the final container (I am not sure if some library installs dependencies specific to that architecture).  The first image is just Node, the second is Node Alpine.  I am not sure if there is some difference that will hurt me later on if I were to copy the modules and transpiled code from the `test` container instead of installing them and transpiling them on the final Alpine container.  That is my root question here.

Comment: I see! 
You can build on alpine node copy the node modules, copy to a regular node with mongo and then copy to alpine node again as the final image.
If anything fails it will fail on your test. But your build and prod would be fine.

As for differences in alpine-node 
The main caveat to note is that it does use musl libc instead of glibc and friends, so certain software might run into issues depending on the depth of their libc requirements. However, most software doesn't have an issue with this.

Comment: tl;dr; unless you use very specific os things, alpine should be perfectly fine to use.

Comment: one final thought, would this be valid as well (pseudo docker) -->


in Node container
install, build, run tests -->


in Node Alpine container
install, build -->



in Final Node Alpine container
copy transpiled js files as well as modules from previous alpine -->

--> done
or is there a specific reason you build on alpine then test that in node (not alpine)?

Comment: I thought you said you needed some mongodb requirement that was not available in alpine. if you can test everything on alpine, you most definitely should test it in alpine.

Comment: I can't test everything in alpine, in the above, only the first container (the non-alpine one) runs the tests

Comment: You can use node for testing and building and alpine for running if you want to. 
If your code is not using any OS Specific modules that node and alpine node has a difference in, there is no reason this should not work. You can also see the differences in musl and glibc here https://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html